# Set log file limit with log4net and azure file appender

Tags: azure, log4net, azure-storage-files

I'm currently using log4net and azure files to store my logs, works ace.

I've been searching and can't find any configuration to make the logger create files no bigger than a given KB size.

This is the configuration I have:

```
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <MaxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <MaximumFileSize value="10KB" />

  <AzureStorageConnectionString value="connectiondatahere" />
  <ShareName value="filelog" />
  <Path value="processor" />
  <File value="processor_{yyyy-MM-dd}.txt" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <ConversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="AzureFileAppender"/>
</root>
```

I've tried a few variations of this configuration but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewed the source code of [log4net-appender-azurefilestorage](https://github.com/CarnivalBen/log4net-appender-azurefilestorage/blob/master/src/AzureFileAppender.cs), I found the log file size limit is not support in azure file appender currently. I suggest you rewrite the azure file appender by yourself and add the size limit feature.

Below are the steps to do it.

Step 1, Add a property named MaximumFileSize to AzureFileAppender class.

```
public int MaximumFileSize { get; set; }
```

Step 2, add the size limit code when appending log to file.

```
protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{
    Initialise(loggingEvent);
    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent));

    if ((_file.Properties.Length + buffer.Length) > MaximumFileSize)
    {
        //do something if the file reach the max file size
    }
    else
    {
        _file.Resize(_file.Properties.Length + buffer.Length);
        using (var fileStream = _file.OpenWrite(null))
        {
            fileStream.Seek(buffer.Length * -1, SeekOrigin.End);
            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3, After that, you could add the size limit(per byte) to configuration file.

```
<MaximumFileSize value="10240" />
```

Comment: Any update? If you have further issues about this topic, please feel free to let me know.